# Jcenter() exception in gradle 2.3

Tags: grails, gradle

I am getting below exception when trying to run  Soapui through gradle. I am using latest gradle 2.3

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-builds'.
> Could not find method JCenter() for arguments [] on repository container.
```

Belos is my `build.gradle`. First I ran without `task wrapper` gave me the same exception , then I added `task wrapper` but still getting the exception. Can someone help, pls?

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        JCenter()
    }    

    dependencies {
        compile files('C:/.../SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/soapui-5.0.0.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: "C:/.../SoapUI-5.0.0/lib", include: '*.jar')

        classpath 'com.lv.plugins:soapui-gradle-plugin:VERSION'
    }
}
soapui {
    test {
        projectFile = 'C:/Users/.../soapui-project.xml'
        printReport = true
        junitReport = true
    }

    tool {
        projectFile = 'C:/../soapui-project.xml'
        iface = 'IOrderService'
        tool = 'wsi,axis1,axis2'
    }
}
```

Comment: It is obvious you didn't even try to Google "JCenter()" at all.

Comment: @JaredBurrows  I did try that but didn't noticed it. May be because I was copy-pasting from [here](https://github.com/willis7/soapui-gradle-plugin).

Comment: ah! You should try to make a pull request to fix it. But accept @Opal's answer.

Comment: I submitted a pull request to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just:

```
jcenter()
```

all lowercase. [See](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html) the docs.

Comment: Thank You! That exception went away.

Comment: It wouldnt let me so soon. In  2 more mins. :)